# Executing JS file using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a node.js script labeled Index.js, I have 1 other file bot.js. Using Node.js how can I execute this file?

```js
var fs = require('fs');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./users/commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

fs.watch('./users', (eventType, filename) => {
    if (eventType === "rename" && filename.includes("txt") != true) {
        let data = fs.readFileSync('./package.json', "utf8");
        console.log("called"); 
        fs.mkdirSync(`./users/${filename}/commands`); 
        commandFiles.forEach(element => {
            fs.writeFileSync(`./users/${filename}/commands/${element}`, data);  
        });
        fs.writeFileSync(`./users/${filename}/package.json`, data);  
        /*
            EXECUTE bot.js HERE
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not wrap that file in a `module.exports` and call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

**index.js file:**

```
const { customCodes } = require('./bot.js');

console.log("Hello World from Node from index.js");

customCodes();
```

**bot.js file:**

```
customCodes = () => {
    console.log('Code from Custom codes');
}

module.exports = {
    customCodes
}
```

Result will be as follows:

```
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js index.js`

Hello World from Node from index.js
Code from Custom codes
```

There are a couple more ways such as setting something as a default exported function or class. But this is one of the simplest ways.